# php script called by ajax not working the same as in apache

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I just ran into an issue where I was trying to assign some values to an array with a numerical index.  This works in a php page on my apache website, but the identical code doesn't work right in a php script that is called by ajax in the same website.  It only works if I assign a letter to the array to turn it from an indexed array to an associative array. Can anyone explain why?

Here is an example of my code:

```
$search = "well,drill rig";
$search1 = array_filter(explode(' ',str_replace(',',' ',$search)));
$val = array();
foreach ($search1 as $key => $value) {
    $val[$key] = $value;
    $q_search.="$val[$key];
}
echo $q_search;
```

On a regular web page, this would output "welldrillrig".
If called by ajax, this returns "wdr". For some reason, it just assigns the first letter of $value to the `$val` array.  I can check `$value` by sending it to `error_log()` and it is the complete string (i.e. "well"), but then `$val[0]` is just "w".  At first I thought it was treating `$val` like a string and returning the offset, but if I `print_r($val)`, I get `[0]=>"w"`.

If I change the code to make `$val` an associative array with a single letter for each key:

```
$keystring = 'abc';
$search = "well,drill rig";
$search1 = array_filter(explode(' ',str_replace(',',' ',$search)));
$val = array();
foreach ($search1 as $key => $value) {
    $keyval = $keystring[$key];
    $val["$keyval"] = $value;
    $q_search.="$val["$keyval"];
}
```

then it works like I would expect.  `$q_search` would equal "welldrillrig" when called with ajax as it would when I run it in apache.

Am I missing something?

Comment: There's no difference between PHP running "regular" and "ajax", they're the same thing. If there's any difference in output, then it's coming from a difference in input.

Comment: Show the Ajax call please

Comment: It sounds like the only difference in how you're calling the PHP is ... the AJAX, right?  So, it stands to reason the problem is in the AJAX/JS.  You need to show us that.